Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/search/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6852
Warning: file_get_contents(/home/search/public_html/wp-content/plugins/open-user-map/open-user-map.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/search/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6852

Warning: file_get_contents(/home/search/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-optimize/wp-optimize.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/search/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6852

Website: renovateserchthailand.com is up and running.
Suddenly get these messages when trying to log in with admin.
Sorry, I am not experienced enough to mess with PHP code.
I deleted both plugins from the server end, but did not help.
What can I do?
Have a nice day /Jan
